# Chat "retry" link eating up text

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

[image]

If a chat message does not get sent for some reason, there's a "retry/cancel" linkset attached to it.  Clicking it works wonders. It also *deletes whatever you've typed in the chatbox*.

By the time the "message failed" thingy pops up, I've already half-typed the next message. I click the retry button, and it gets sent--but then I have to type my message all over again. It's pretty unexpected behaviour--I can understand that pressing the up arrow will empty the box (since nearly all of us have used a shell at one point or the other), but not this.

This has happened to me often--my ISP is rather evil so the retry thingy comes often.

I can guess what's happening here--the retry button is hijacking the textarea to send the message--it's probably just recopying the text into the textarea and jQuery-voodoo-clicking "send".

Could this be tweaked so that it saves the typed text *before* hijacking the textarea and places the text back in place? Even better would be if it preserves the cursor. The best thing to do would be to make it not hijack the textarea in the first place.

Comment: yeah, this can be annoying. Thankfully for me, [Lazarus](http://lazarus.interclue.com/) had saved me from quite a lot of frustration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I can guess what's happening here--the retry button is hijacking the textarea to send the message--it's probably just recopying the text into the textarea and jQuery-voodoo-clicking "send".

I have to admit you had almost convinced me that that's what we do, but we actually don't :)

The issue was just that the "submit an edit to a previous message", "submit a new message", and "re-submit a failed message" are using the same functionality (Code reuse! DRY! Awesome, right?).

Part of that code was to clear the input box, which of course makes sense in two of those three use cases. After you've pulled yourself some freshly baked JavaScript, it won't do it anymore in the third case.

Comment: Nearly the same as the textarea thing--just without the voodoo :) Thanks for fixing it!